# Loading JSON file similar to XML in scala

Tags: json, scala

I'm refactoring a system (written in scala) which was earlier using XML files to one using JSON files.

In a test case, an XML file is read as follows

```
import scala.xml.XML
val xml = XML.loadFile("/Users/al/Projects/Scala/yahoo-weather.xml")
```

A value is read using an XPath,

```
val temp = (xml \\ "channel" \\ "item" \ "condition" \ "@temp") text
```

I'm unsure of how to do this with JSON. Is there anything similar to use?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at [json4s](http://json4s.org/)

There is support for xPath like expressions

Copied from website

> scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
>
> scala> import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
>
> scala> val json =
>
> ```
>   ("person" ->
>     ("name" -> "Joe") ~
>     ("age" -> 35) ~
>     ("spouse" ->
>       ("person" ->
>         ("name" -> "Marilyn") ~
>         ("age" -> 33)
>       )
>     )
>   )
> ```
>
> scala> json \ "spouse"
>
> res0: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(
>         (person,JObject(List((name,JString(Marilyn)), (age,JInt(33)))))))
>
> scala> compact(render(res0))
>
> res1: String = {"person":{"name":"Marilyn","age":33}}
>
> scala> compact(render(json \ "name"))
>
> res2: String = {"name":"Joe","name":"Marilyn"}
>
> scala> compact(render((json removeField { _ == JField("name", JString("Marilyn")) }) \ "name"))
>
> res3: String = {"name":"Joe"}
>
> scala> compact(render(json \ "person" \ "name"))
>
> res4: String = "Joe"

Comment: thanks, Could you let me know how I would read a json file as well.

Comment: Use json4s `parse` combined with scala `Source.fromFile` or java `Files.readAllBytes` i.e. `parse(Source.fromFile("blah.json").mkString))`

Answer (score 0):

There are various libraries available to work with JSON in Scala. I've been using [circe](http://circe.io) just recently and can highly recommend it. You can use it in combination with [optics](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html) to easily traverse and modify your JSON, e.g. (example copied from website):

```
import cats.syntax.either._
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._

val json: Json = parse("""
{
  "order": {
    "customer": {
      "name": "Custy McCustomer",
      "contactDetails": {
        "address": "1 Fake Street, London, England",
        "phone": "0123-456-789"
      }
    },
    "items": [{
      "id": 123,
      "description": "banana",
      "quantity": 1
    }, {
      "id": 456,
      "description": "apple",
      "quantity": 2
    }],
    "total": 123.45
  }
}
""").getOrElse(Json.Null)

import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._
// import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._

val _phoneNum = root.order.customer.contactDetails.phone.string
// _phoneNum: monocle.Optional[io.circe.Json,String] = monocle.POptional$$anon$1@4f5b626d

val phoneNum: Option[String] = _phoneNum.getOption(json)
// phoneNum: Option[String] = Some(0123-456-789)
```

You can also define en-/decoders to covert JSON objects to/from case classes or use boilerplate-free generic derivation.